# Open EXR file not getting generated in certain cases

Tags: render-passes, .exr, depth-map

I am trying to generate an OpenEXR file based on the following procedure :
[Getting the depth of every pixel to the center of projection of the camera in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238218/getting-the-depth-of-every-pixel-to-the-center-of-projection-of-the-camera-in-bl)

I have tried to create a simple scene with a cube and a camera (default scene in blender) and the above procedure works well and I am also able to save the pass data in an open EXR file using the file output node in blender.

However, on downloading the demo files provided on the blender's website: https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/

The OpenEXR file simply doesn't get created. I have tried with the classroom demo file as well as the architectural visualization file. The below are the screenshots that I tried with for the Architectural Visualization under the compositor window:
[image]

[image]

Are there any specifics that I am missing out on?

Comment: Make sure *Compositing* *(Output Properties > Post Processing)* and *Use Nodes (Compositor header)* is ticked and press F12 to render the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,this works :)